# ¿Cómo evitar errores en Input del Usuario?

Tags: python

Estoy escribiendo un código en `Python 3.6` para calificar un examen, pero quiero una forma en la que si el usuario comete un error al escribir la respuesta, pueda corregirlo sin tener que volver a iniciar todo de nuevo.

O que si introduce otra letra que no esté en las respuestas aparezca una advertencia

> Por favor teclee una opción aceptada.

Mi código es el siguiente, utilizo un diccionario con las respuestas para hacer la comparación:

```
Rserie_2 = {'1':'C','2':'A','3':'B','4':'C','5':'C','6':'B','7':'C','8':'C','9':'B','10':'A','11':'B'}

def serie2():
print('\nPor favor escriba las respuestas contestadas en la Serie II. (A,B,C)\n')
a2 = 0
e2 = 0

s2p1 = input('Pregunta 1 >> ')
s2p1 = s2p1.upper()
s2r1 = Rserie_2['1']
if s2p1 == s2r1:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p2 = input('\nPregunta 2 >> ')
s2p2 = s2p2.upper()
s2r2 = Rserie_2['2']
if s2p2 == s2r2:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p3 = input('\nPregunta 3 >> ')
s2p3 = s2p3.upper()
s2r3 = Rserie_2['3']
if s2p3 == s2r3:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p4 = input('\nPregunta 4 >> ')
s2p4 = s2p4.upper()
s2r4 = Rserie_2['4']
if s2p4 == s2r4:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p5 = input('\nPregunta 5 >> ')
s2p5 = s2p5.upper()
s2r5 = Rserie_2['5']
if s2p5 == s2r5:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p6 = input('\nPregunta 6 >> ')
s2p6 = s2p6.upper()
s2r6 = Rserie_2['6']
if s2p6 == s2r6:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p7 = input('\nPregunta 7 >> ')
s2p7 = s2p7.upper()
s2r7 = Rserie_2['7']
if s2p7 == s2r7:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p8 = input('\nPregunta 8 >> ')
s2p8 = s2p8.upper()
s2r8 = Rserie_2['8']
if s2p8 == s2r8:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p9 = input('\nPregunta 9 >> ')
s2p9 = s2p9.upper()
s2r9 = Rserie_2['9']
if s2p9 == s2r9:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p10 = input('\nPregunta 10 >> ')
s2p10 = s2p10.upper()
s2r10 = Rserie_2['10']
if s2p10 == s2r10:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

s2p11 = input('\nPregunta 11 >> ')
s2p11 = s2p11.upper()
s2r11 = Rserie_2['11']
if s2p11 == s2r11:
    a2 += 1
    e2
    print('¡Correcto!')
else:
    a2
    e2 += 1
    print('Incorrecto.')

c2 = a2*2

rangoS2 = ''
if a2 == 11:
    rangoS2 = 'Superior. (SUP)\n'
elif a2 == 10:
    rangoS2 = 'Superior al Término Medio. (S.T.M.)\n'
elif a2 == 9:
    rangoS2 = 'Término Medio Alto. (T.M.A.)\n'
elif a2 == 8:
    rangoS2 = 'Témino Medio. (T.M.)\n'
elif a2 == 7:
    rangoS2 = 'Término Medio Bajo. (T.M.B.)\n'
elif a2 == 6:
    rangoS2 = 'Inferior al Término Medio. (I.T.M.)\n'
elif a2 <= 5:
    rangoS2 = 'Inferior. (INF)\n'

return a2, c2, rangoS2
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so] Jorimica. deberias aclarar que entradas son válidas (por ejemplo letras A, B, C, y D son válidas, otra cosa no). Por otro lado, si introduciendo una opción válida pero erronea ¿quieres que vuelva a preguntar la misma pregunta hasta que acierte? Tu código se puede reducir mucho, estas repitiendo el mismo código sin necesidad pero deberias aclara lo que expongo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! Exactamente, las entradas válidas son A, B y C. Sin embargo, el código es solamente para calificar un examen que se hace en papel, entonces lo que quiero evitar es algún error que pudiera tener la persona que califica al "copiar" las respuestas que están en papel. Por ejemplo, que repita accidentalmente una respuesta. Pensaba poner una opción al final que pregunte si está todo correcto y continuar o si desea volver a calificar, pero no sé si sea lo mejor.

Comment: Validar que solo ingrese A, B y C es trivial, otra cosa es que ingrese una A por una C... Eso no se puede validar, solo el usuario puede validar eso volviendo a comprobar las respuestas en el papel. Lo que puedes hacer es o bien preguntarle dos veces cada respuesta (el tipico`A seleccionado "C" ¿Desea confirmar?`) o creas una tabla resúmen al final para que vuelva a mirar opción por opción si las ha introducido bien, si no dar la opción de correguir la que quiera. Ambas son fáciles de implementar, solo debes elegir la opción que más te guste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es ir guardando los datos en otro diccionario y al final de ser ingresados todas las respuestas, imprimir un resúmen con las preguntas y sus opciones ingresadas para que puedan ser revisadas. Hecho esto, se da la opción de terminar y retornar lo que hay o modificar alguna o algunas respuestas que estubieran erróneamente ingresadas. El código se puede refactorizar mucho, si usas un `for` e iteras sobre el diccionario te evitas tener tanto código repetitivo. Un ejemplo de lo anterior podría ser:

```
import collections
import textwrap

Rserie_2 = {'1':'C','2':'A','3':'B','4':'C','5':'C','6':'B','7':'C','8':'C','9':'B','10':'A','11':'B'}

def serie2():
    print('\nPor favor escriba las respuestas contestadas en la Serie II. (A,B,C)\n')
    opciones = set(('A', 'B', 'C'))
    respuestas = collections.OrderedDict()

    for pregunta, respuesta in sorted(Rserie_2.items(), key= lambda x: int(x[0])):
        while True:
            opcion = input(f'Pregunta {pregunta} >> ').upper()
            if opcion in opciones:
                respuestas[pregunta] = opcion
                break
            else:
                print('ERROR: opción no válida. Vuelva a introducirla.')

    menu = '''

        Resúmen:
            Aciertos: {}.
            Errores: {}.
            Rango: {}.

        REVISE CUIDADOSAMENTE SI EXISTEN ERRORES Y ELIJA UNA OPCIÓN:
            0 -> Modificar respuesta
            1 -> Validar datos y terminar'''

    while True:
        aciertos = sum(respuestas[key] == Rserie_2[key] for key in Rserie_2.keys())
        errores = len(Rserie_2) - aciertos

        if aciertos == 11:
            rango = 'Superior. (SUP)\n'
        elif aciertos == 10:
            rango = 'Superior al Término Medio. (S.T.M.)\n'
        elif aciertos == 9:
            rango = 'Término Medio Alto. (T.M.A.)\n'
        elif aciertos == 8:
            rango = 'Témino Medio. (T.M.)\n'
        elif aciertos == 7:
            rango = 'Término Medio Bajo. (T.M.B.)\n'
        elif aciertos == 6:
            rango = 'Inferior al Término Medio. (I.T.M.)\n'
        elif aciertos <= 5:
            rango = 'Inferior. (INF)\n'

        print(f'\n{"="*60}\nRESULTADOS SERIE\n{"="*60}')
        for pregunta, respuesta in respuestas.items():
            print(f'Pregunta {pregunta} >> {respuesta}')

        print(textwrap.dedent(menu.format(aciertos, errores, rango.strip())))

        while True:
            op = input('-> ')
            if op == '0':
                while True:
                    pregunta = input('Ingrese el número de pregunta a modificar o nada para salir: ')
                    if not pregunta:
                        break
                    if pregunta in respuestas:
                        while True:
                            opcion = input(f'Pregunta {pregunta} >> ').upper()
                            if opcion in opciones:
                                respuestas[pregunta] = opcion
                                break
                            else:
                                print('ERROR: opción no válida. Vuelva a introducirla.')
                    else:
                        print('ERROR: Número de pregunta inválido.')
                break

            elif op == '1':
                return aciertos, errores, rango
            else:
                print('Opción no válida, intentelo de nuevo')
```

**Un ejemplo de ejecución:**

> ```
> Por favor escriba las respuestas contestadas en la Serie II. (A,B,C)
>
> Pregunta 1 >> a
> Pregunta 2 >> a
> Pregunta 3 >> c
> Pregunta 4 >> c
> Pregunta 5 >> c
> Pregunta 6 >> b
> Pregunta 7 >> b
> Pregunta 8 >> c
> Pregunta 9 >> b
> Pregunta 10 >> c
> Pregunta 11 >> b
>
> ============================================================
> RESULTADOS SERIE
> ============================================================
> Pregunta 1 >> A
> Pregunta 2 >> A
> Pregunta 3 >> C
> Pregunta 4 >> C
> Pregunta 5 >> C
> Pregunta 6 >> B
> Pregunta 7 >> B
> Pregunta 8 >> C
> Pregunta 9 >> B
> Pregunta 10 >> C
> Pregunta 11 >> B
>
>
> Resúmen:
>     Aciertos: 7.
>     Errores: 4.
>     Rango: Término Medio Bajo. (T.M.B.).
>
> REVISE CUIDADOSAMENTE SI EXISTEN ERRORES Y ELIJA UNA OPCIÓN:
>     0 -> Modificar respuesta
>     1 -> Validar datos y terminar
> ->
> ```

Si tienes más series es muy simple modificar esta función para que pasandole como argumento el diccionario de opciones correctas te sirva para ingresar cualquier serie de preguntas.

En el código se usan literales de cadena formateados (`f'Hola {nombre}'`). Esto solo funciona en Python 3.6 en adelante (afirmas usar esta versión). Para versiones anteriores se pueden sustituir pot `str.format` sin problemas.

Si el código se va a usar por casualidad en la "vida real" **debe ser testeado adecuadamente**. Creo no haber cometido errores pero estos pueden existir de todas formas.